# How I can move record to another collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently, I have a lot of records that need to be moved to another collection.

I try with aggregate with $out operator, but it will delete and create a new collection.

I don't know mongo had an operator to handle this issue, if yes please give me a link or document

Comment: Use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [copyTo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) or use find with forEach, for example:

```
db.collection1.find().forEach(docs => db.collection2.insert(docs));
```

Or you can use [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/) and [mongostore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/)

Comment: I don't want manually moving, because it took many times for fetching data. I want to move with only one query